# Password in database different from password obtained with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to read user password from MySql database. The issue is, that it seems the password obtained from database is not the same as the password stored in the database, so I'm getting authentication error.

What makes it even stranger is that it seems after application restart I keep getting different passwords. Since I can't really find a similar topic I'm sure I have overlooked some basic stuff but I just can't see where. Here is my configure:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(new PasswordAuthentication())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT user_name, user_password, verified "
                    + "FROM user_details "
                    + "WHERE user_email = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT user_name, user_role_desc "
                    + "FROM user_details "
                    + "WHERE user_email = ?");
}
```

PasswordEncoder is custom but as I understand Security should just call the matches method:

```
public boolean matches(CharSequence password, String token)
{
    System.out.println(password);
    System.out.println(token);
```

And this is where I see that token is different from the one stored in the database even though the pattern is the same.

I have a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter but no other custom implementation. Does anything else in the chain modify the password obtained from the database?

EDIT:
The password in the database is:

$22$17$9GD7-A8_W4h9q4_uJ-fFSMhJjKMIbKNJng-G6IfzNCQ

While if I print out the - supposedly same - password returned by jdbcAuthentication then I see:

Password 1:
`$22$17$c-gMYpcX5d0YOgf6HBs19MuImTq7wb41tBeKSTw1mMw`

This remains the same in the log as long as I don't restart the application. If I restart, then it will be different, eg:

`$22$17$zG0Ph1AM9_xAADIR8l01JVkCNzNwk_s0Z4VJt49NSiU`

Then third time:
`$22$17$B4y1Yr8Mt0QuuMg-AK6x02RyAZlQVnbo9A6KKEYitlE`

etc. But as long as I don't restart the app the password returned by jdbcAuthentication remains the same - just not the one that is in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I think I got it. The fault was, that I thought that both `usersByUsernameQuery` and `authoritiesByUsernameQuery` are by default prepared with the value extracted from the request.

This is not the case. The `authoritiesByUsernameQuery` is prepared with the result of the first column returned by the `usersByUsernameQuery`. This broke the process as I have used the email address in the validation but in the first query I still selected `user_name` to be returned, therefore the authorities query failed.